# Android - In Preferences get an image uri from stock Gallery

Tags: android, android-intent, gallery, preferences, sharedpreferences

I need to retrieve images Uri from stock Gallery and save it to sharedPreferences, in order to let the user choose a custom wallpaper for a live wallpaper.

From preferences I can call an Intent programmatically this way:

```
intentPref.setIntent(new Intent().setAction(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
    .setData(android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI));
```

or I can load it from XML, but I don't know how to get the result from the Intent (as in startActivityForResult), so I can save the Uri to SharedPreferences.

Any ideas?